# How to draw a half-rounded rectangle?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rounded-corners

I want a a half-rounded rectangle like in the image, but rounded only 2 edges.

[image: A Half-Rounded Rectangle]

I have tried using `RadiusX="" RadiusY=""`, but that rounded all 4 edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a `Border` you can specify four different radiuses (`topLeft`, `topRight`, `bottomRight`, `bottomLeft`) separated by a comma, e.g.:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" Margin="10">
    <TextBlock>....</TextBlock>
</Border>
```